# VS2010 Intellisense for ASP.NET objects disappears after 10 seconds

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress, intellisense

I recently acquired VS2010 to run one of our global 2010 projects. Among other assemblies, it runs the ajaxcontroltoolkit, web.UI.extensions as well as Devexpress (third party). Due to project standardization we put in the assembly registers at the top of the aspx file as so.

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.v10.2, Version=10.2.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" Namespace="DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView" TagPrefix="dx" %>    
<%@ Register assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors.v10.2, Version=10.2.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" namespace="DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors" tagprefix="dx" %>
```

Problem comes now that my ASP.net objects (like asp:Textbox) intellisense does not work for the .aspx pages. Works fine for code-behind pages. I have tried the following :-

1. Import settings from a colleague without this problem
2. Set to default settings
3. Default the %AppCode%/Microsoft/Visual Studio/10.0 folder
4. Repairing / re-installing the third party (DevExpress)

Curious now after closing and opening my solution repeatedly, I found that the asp.net Intellisense actually works when the solution is newly opened. However, during this time my DevExpress intellisense does not. After approximately 10 seconds, the DevExpress intellisense now works, but all my asp.net intellisense does not. Which leads me to believe there's some conflict somewhere but ***how do I fix this***?

Comment: try to report them in connect forums. they will respond you shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I placed the AjaxControlToolkit assembly reference below the DevExpress references and now I get all my intellisense working as per normal. Can't say I understand how it works now. Below are the steps I took :-

1. Remove AjaxControlToolkit reference - ASP.net and DevExpress intellisense present
2. Placed AjaxControlToolkit reference in web.config - all 3 intellisense present
3. Placed AjaxControlToolkit reference under DevExpress reference - all 3 intellisense present

It's possible that we removing and replacing the AjaxControlToolkit reference refresh the linkage somehow - a linkage that was previous blocking intellisense access to the ASP.net objects. Anyway I'm just glad it works now.

*edit : realized the solution was just to rename the tagprefix of AjaxControlToolkit to something else besides asp. Something about AjaxControlToolkit was giving me trouble and some VS2010 and because it shared the asp tagprefix, all asp objects stopped working. I renamed it to "ajax" and now I see all my asp objects though the "ajax" objects still do not work.*